# Script to xcopy data to remote computer by name

Tags: powershell, batch-file, xcopy

I'm able to xcopy myFolder to Xmachine but I was wondering if you guys know of a way/have a script to prompt for "what folder" to "computer name" and a side note when to use "echo" and it's purpose.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, create a PSSession using the New-PSSession command and you can pass it in then Copy-Item -ToPSession
You can modify the following to your need (you might need to specify credentials to create the PSSession) and then wrap it into a PowerShell function:

```
$pssession=New-PSSession - Computername $Computername
Copy-Item -ToSession $pssession -Path $path  -Destination $destination -Recurse
Remove-PSSession $pssession
```

Comment: Make sure your environment supports remoting.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to user [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) for robust copy-tasks.

You can combine it with powershell, a very simple example:

```
$whereto = Read-Host "where to"
robocopy C:\SchedTasks $whereto /MIR  /w:10 /r:2 /v /tee /fp /eta
```

$whereto could be "c:\temp" or "\computer1\c$\temp"
The other parameters are wait and retry and some verbose/display stuff for more information. You can look them op on the page i linked.

EDIT

Concerning your "echo" question. Its a function within a batch file that enables or disabled onscreen messages.